# How is it possible to access the instance variable of aa abstract class to a class?

Tags: java

How can I use this abstract class instance variable in my DemoAbs class?

This is the D class:

```
abstract class D {
    int i=10;
    String str="java";

    D(){
        System.out.println("called abstract class constructor");
    }

    abstract void m1();
    void m2() {
        int i=20;
        System.out.println("called m2() in abstract class !");
    }
}
```

This is the DemoAbs class:

```
public class DemoAbs extends D{

    // access instance variable here from abstract class

    DemoAbs() {
         System.out.println("called DemoAbs class constr");

    }

    @Override
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("inside m1() method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoAbs d=new DemoAbs();
        d.m1();
        d.m2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to just access it from `DemoAbs` as if it's an instance variable of that class?

Comment: in place of comment, write `int j = i;`

Comment: For `DemoAbs`, `D` is not an abstract class but his super class, so it is part of the instance, every accessible fields will be available (accessible, so private won't be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accessing instance fields of a superclass from a subclass is simple: just use the name of these instance fields as-is. The only caveat: these fields must have the proper visibility. In your case you define the `i` field to have default visibility which may not always work[1]. To make sure the field is visible to subclasses it should be defined with the `protected` visibility.

Here's your program (slightly adapted) that shows this:

```
abstract class D {
  protected int i=10;
  protected String str="java";

  D(){
    System.out.println("called abstract class constructor");
  }

  protected abstract void m1();

  void m2() {
    System.out.println("called m2() in abstract class! i=" + i);
  }
}




public class DemoAbs extends D{

  // access instance variable here from abstract class

  DemoAbs() {
    System.out.println("called DemoAbs class constr");
  }

  @Override
  protected void m1() {
    i = 30;
    System.out.println("inside m1() method");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoAbs d=new DemoAbs();
    d.m1();  // Output: "inside m1() method"
    d.m2();  // Output: "called m2() in abstract class! i=30"
  }
}
```

Note that the call to d.m2() will produce output which says `"i=30"`. That's because the call to d.m1() carried out the assignment `i = 30` (see body of of `DemoAbs.m1()`) thus changing `i` from its initial value (`10` see its declaration in `D`).

[1] Specifically, if the subclass is declared in a different package than the superclass, a field with default visibility will not be visible to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **super** keyword to access superclass non private variables from methods of subclass

Your code(modified):

```
abstract class D {
    int i = 10;
    String str = "java";
    private String newStr = "java not accessible";
    D() {
        System.out.println("called abstract class construtar");
    }
    abstract void m1();
    void m2() {
        int i = 20;
        System.out.println("called m2() Abstrate class !");
    }
}

public class DemoAbs extends D {
    // access instance variable here from abstract class
    DemoAbs() {
        System.out.println("called DemoAbs class contr");
    }

    @Override
    void m1() {
        System.out.println(super.i); // added
        System.out.println(super.str); // added
        //System.out.println(super.newStr); -- Not accessible
        System.out.println("inside m1() method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoAbs d = new DemoAbs();
        d.m1();
        d.m2();
    }
}
```

Comment: `super.` is superfluous in this example. It's also an antipattern to access non-constant supertype variable members directly. Use a non-private accessor method.

Comment: Agreed. Varibles must be declared private and non private accessor methods should be used for accessing attributes of a class from any other class(be it a subclass or not) as a best practice. I mentioned super here as the super class variables in the question were not private and super can be used as a way to access superclass non private members.

Answer (score 0):

Simply In your main method just do this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoAbs d=new DemoAbs();
        d.m1();
        d.m2();
        int num = d.i;
        String strVar = d.str;

    }
```

Now variable **num** and **strVar**  are holding the values of the member variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can define getter method for instance variables in abstract class D and access it using DemoAbs class instance.